# Push notification or any other better approach?

Tags: ios, push-notification

I am creating an iOS application and its scenario is: 
A user orders something from a vendor. When he places the order, the app asks him to wait. I want the user to know when the vendor accepts/reject the order. 
Am I supposed to use push notifications for this purpose or is there any other better approach?

Comment: Yes, use a push notification.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The simple answer is yes. A push notification is the best way to update a user. The advantage of using a push notification is that the user no longer has to be in the app to receive this update. However if they are still in the app you can handle the content in the push notification payload. For example you could show a success message or failure message.